# shell script failing when called by windows-netcat

Tags: linux, windows, shell, netcat

I'm using netcat on my windows machine to call xinetd on a linux machine which executes my shell script. When doing this on linux -> linux it works fine, when doing this on windows -> linux it doesn't work. I'm not sure if a CRLF could be the problem.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
CMD="unknown"
CODE="unknown"

while read line;
do
  CMD=`echo ${line} | cut -d"=" -f1`
  CODE=`echo ${line} | cut -d"=" -f2`

  printf "CMD:#%s#\n" $CMD >> /tmp/xinetd.txt;
  printf "CODE:#%s#\n\n" $CODE >> /tmp/xinetd.txt

  case $CMD in
  key)
     case $CODE in
     100 | 150 | 200 | 250 | 300 | 350 | 400 | 450)
        echo $CMD $CODE
     ;;
     *)
       CMD="unknown"
     ;;
     esac
  ;;
  *)
    CMD="unknown"
  ;;
  esac
  break
done

if [ "${CMD}" == "unknown" ]
then
   echo ERROR=3
   exit 3
fi
```

## Windows -> Linux call:

```
echo key=100 | ncat.exe myip myport

Debugging-File: 
----------------------------------------------------
CMD:#key#
CODE:#100#

#ODE:# (I don't know where this is coming from ... is it line 17 echo $CMD $CODE? Buf if yeah, why formatting fails and I'm getting error?)

Return: 
----------------------------------------------------
ERROR=3
close: No error
```

## Linux -> Linux call:

```
echo key=100 | nc myip myport

Debugging-File:
----------------------------------------------------
CMD:#key#
CODE:#100#

Return: 
----------------------------------------------------
key=100
```

Any Idea?

## Edit 1.1:

Okay, it seems like it is a CRLF problem. I got the tipp, that I should create a file UNIX - ANSI (file.txt) in Notepad++ with the same commadn I did one cho before (key=100), and doing

```
type file.txt | ncat.exe myip myport
```

This works fine. Now I'm trying to fix this issue on linux side ... I'm no xinetd guru but my idea was to do a

```
tr "\r\n" "\n"
```

before calling my shell-script above.

My xinetd-service:

```
service myservice
{
    type            = UNLISTED
    port            = myport
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    cps             = 100 3
    instances       = 500
    per_source      = 250
    flags           = NODELAY
    user            = myuser
    server          = myscript.sh
    server_args     = -e | /usr/bin/tr "\r\n" "\n"
    disable         = no
}
```

Actual same result as before:

```
CMD:#key#
CODE:#100#

#ODE:#
```

## Solution: This is weird. I edited 2 lines in my shell script and added 2 lines:

```
  CMD=`echo $line | tr "\r\n" "\n" | cut -d = -f1`
  CODE=`echo $line | tr "\r\n" "\n" | cut -d = -f2`

  CMD=`echo $CODE | sed "s/ //g"`
  CODE=`echo $CODE | sed "s/ //g"`
```

My printf didn't showed me a leading space character on the $CODE. That was the problem.

Comment: you gave a great first question, with sample code, output, explanation. Now your edit is incomprehensible (by comparison). Either post a new question (with same qualities as above), or edit your "template" above with the new information. `netcat` solutions are pretty fragile, you would do better to get `ssh`, `scp` etc working. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I hope it looks better now.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the problem is a DOS carriage return.  Which part of this do you need help with?

Comment: `dos2unix file` on the linux side will get rid of any `\r` chars. You can reduce your `tr` to `tr -d '\012'` to delete the \r chars. Some versions of `tr`s won't understand `tr '\r\n' '\n'` as you have it (but if it's working, no worries!). You can post your solution as an an answer, and accept it 48 hrs later, to gain reputation points here on S.O. for yourself. Good luck.